# TableViewCell button click not registered when loaded below screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiscrollview

My main view is a scroll view and inside this view I have a content View. Inside this view I have three different tableviews. The tableviews have a variable number of rows and I set each tableView height at run time depending on how many cells there are.

e.g. TableView 1 has row height of 72 and at run time there are three rows. So the tableView height is equal to 72*3 = 216

I then disable the TableViews from scrolling so that I have a nice easy scroll through my entire view. In each of the tableView cells there are buttons that perform certain actions. These buttons work perfectly using button tags and an action tied to each. Here's the problem though...

These buttons only work if they are on the screen at the initial time of load. If my scroll view goes past the bottom of the screen, all buttons become inactive. It doesn't matter what TableView goes past the edge of the screen, all buttons below will no longer work.

I've read some forums about setting the content view height to the entire height of the scroll view before loading the tableView data, but this does not seem to work. Here's the code I use to change my scrollView/contentView height before loading tableData. I can show any other code you deem necessary to help with the issue.

```
totalHeight = self.friendsTableHeight.constant + self.invitationsTableHeight.constant + self.suggestionsTableHeight.constant + 350
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: totalHeight)
self.contentViewHeight.constant = totalHeight

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.suggestionsTable.dataSource = self
    self.friendsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.invitationsTableView.dataSource = self
    self.suggestionsTable.reloadData()
    self.friendsTableView.reloadData()
    self.invitationsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

I also attempted to set my contentView to clipToBounds, but this will cut off any part of the table that is below the screen. Been researching this for a few hours now and hoping someone may have come across this before!

Comment: you must be knowing that table view cells are reused. The table view cell that is going out of visible view is used to display the next. My guess is it has to do with that.

Comment: I think you did not add constraints which will benefit your UI.

Comment: I went through and recreated all constraints. Made sure that my content view was the proper height for all tables and then reloaded the tables. It just seems like it refuses to load the rows that are beneath the screen until I scroll down. At that point, the buttons do not work in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code or how you have your constraints setup, tough to say what you are doing wrong. However...

Here is a simple example of 3 tableViews laid-out vertically in a scrollView, with 40-pts vertical spacing between them. The buttons in the cells work fine, regardless of scroll position.

The storyboard layout looks like this:

[image]

The result:

[image]

After scrolling down:

[image]

The code:

```
//
//  TablesInScrollViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 11/7/18.
//

import UIKit

class ButtonCell: UITableViewCell {

    let theButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        v.setTitle("Button", for: .normal)
        return v
    }()

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(theButton)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            theButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            theButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            theButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: theButton.leadingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            ])

        theButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Button tapped for:", theLabel.text ?? "")
    }

}

class TablesInScrollViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableA: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var tableB: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var tableC: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var tableAHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tableBHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet var tableCHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var aData = ["A - 1", "A - 2", "A - 3", "A - 4", "A - 5", "A - 6"]
    var bData = ["B - 1", "B - 2", "B - 3", "B - 4", "B - 5", "B - 6", "B - 7", "B - 8", "B - 9", "B - 10"]
    var cData = ["C - 1", "C - 2", "C - 3", "C - 4"]

    var rHeight = 72

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let theData = tableView.isEqual(tableA) ? aData : tableView.isEqual(tableB) ? bData : cData
        return theData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ButtonCell", for: indexPath) as! ButtonCell

        let theData = tableView.isEqual(tableA) ? aData : tableView.isEqual(tableB) ? bData : cData
        cell.theLabel.text = theData[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        [tableA, tableB, tableC].forEach {
            $0?.dataSource = self
            $0?.delegate = self
            $0?.register(ButtonCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ButtonCell")
            $0?.rowHeight = CGFloat(rHeight)
        }

        tableAHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(rHeight * aData.count)
        tableBHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(rHeight * bData.count)
        tableCHeightConstraint.constant = CGFloat(rHeight * cData.count)

    }

}
```

and the Storyboard source (to help you get the constraints right):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="llR-vr-4Zy">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Tables In Scroll View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="7Zm-EI-Mg7">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="llR-vr-4Zy" customClass="TablesInScrollViewController" customModule="SW4Temp" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="tw7-gs-oZR">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <scrollView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="GnA-uY-k8D">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="40" width="335" height="607"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="PBs-dW-Koi">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="7.5" y="8" width="319" height="128"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="BKq-4w-98u"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </tableView>
                                    <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="nk6-mF-h3T">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="7.5" y="176" width="319" height="128"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="Z9y-eh-Yju"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </tableView>
                                    <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Exi-mx-rcW">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="7.5" y="344" width="319" height="128"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="128" id="qti-gs-wLU"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </tableView>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.58980089430000004" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="PBs-dW-Koi" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="GnA-uY-k8D" secondAttribute="width" constant="-16" id="Axl-cT-hm3"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Exi-mx-rcW" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="nk6-mF-h3T" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="G1C-SH-ONS"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nk6-mF-h3T" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="PBs-dW-Koi" secondAttribute="centerX" id="MjW-Yu-9Bi"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Exi-mx-rcW" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="R5m-2G-ZHN"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="PBs-dW-Koi" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="GnA-uY-k8D" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="UZj-KF-b8H"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="PBs-dW-Koi" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="GnA-uY-k8D" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="bhx-EO-I8M"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Exi-mx-rcW" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="nk6-mF-h3T" secondAttribute="centerX" id="gF2-Nw-sxy"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="Exi-mx-rcW" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="nk6-mF-h3T" secondAttribute="width" id="glB-2g-ALO"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="PBs-dW-Koi" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="n5L-uV-uAN"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nk6-mF-h3T" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="PBs-dW-Koi" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="40" id="ppi-8s-Y5S"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="nk6-mF-h3T" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="PBs-dW-Koi" secondAttribute="width" id="qFz-lA-ieI"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="0.83234566450000003" blue="0.47320586440000001" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="V6X-c3-PaY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="GnA-uY-k8D" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="0Ev-px-vRN"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="GnA-uY-k8D" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="V6X-c3-PaY" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="3sa-DD-wMb"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="V6X-c3-PaY" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="GnA-uY-k8D" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Dji-Cc-aaB"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="GnA-uY-k8D" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="V6X-c3-PaY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="ZKZ-mu-117"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="V6X-c3-PaY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="tableA" destination="PBs-dW-Koi" id="Cnm-we-nuM"/>
                        <outlet property="tableAHeightConstraint" destination="BKq-4w-98u" id="6mm-8g-BQL"/>
                        <outlet property="tableB" destination="nk6-mF-h3T" id="yEs-cv-Zld"/>
                        <outlet property="tableBHeightConstraint" destination="Z9y-eh-Yju" id="oC8-9g-71b"/>
                        <outlet property="tableC" destination="Exi-mx-rcW" id="UhD-rh-9Kw"/>
                        <outlet property="tableCHeightConstraint" destination="qti-gs-wLU" id="ej2-mK-5YT"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="kfo-TI-SEb" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="31" y="48"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```